# Formula to calculate DATE as TEXT

Tags: excel, sharepoint, formula, sharepoint-online, formulas

I have searched online and in forums but can´t find any solution for this.

I want to calculate date as TEXT in Sharepoint list with calculated fields.

It works to calculate well with the formula below, but it prints the date like this "2018-07-06T22:00:00Z"

=IF(ISBLANK([Contract Start]);"";DATE(YEAR([Contract Start]);MONTH([Contract Start])+[ContractLength];DAY([Contract Start])))

I have tried the following formula, and it gives me the date in the format i wish "2018-07-06" but i can´t get it to add months from column [ContractLength] to the date.

=IF(ISBLANK([ContractStarts]);””;CONCATENATE(TEXT([ContractStarts];"yyyy");"-";TEXT([ContractStarts];"MM");"-";TEXT([ContractStarts];"dd")))

So I need help with a formula that adds the specified number of months from the [ContractLength] column to the start date [ContractStarts] column in the SharePoint list, and print it as TEXT so we get the date printed "2018-07-06".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `TEXT([ContractStarts];"yyyy-mm-dd")` ? It is text-that-looks-like-a-date, not a real date.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Yes it should solve the formatting, but not the calculation.

Comment: I think @Jeeped meant `=IF(ISBLANK([Contract Start]);"";TEXT(DATE(YEAR([Contract Start]);MONTH([Contract Start])+[ContractLength];DAY([Contract Start]);"yyyy-mm-dd")))` *I might have the closing parentheses incorrect*

Comment: Hi thank for sharing, Your code doesnt work, it gives error as well when trying to save it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean with "calculate date as text". If you mean you want to show the result as text, not a date, then you can use this formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(ContractStarts);"";TEXT(DATE(YEAR(ContractStarts);MONTH(ContractStarts)+ContractLength;DAY(ContractStarts));"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Or, if you want the result to be a date, then this formula works fine, too, but you need to select "Date" as the data type of the calculated column and tick the button for Date only.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(ContractStarts);"",DATE(YEAR(ContractStarts);MONTH(ContractStarts)+ContractLength;DAY(ContractStarts)))
```

[image]

The screenshot below shows both formulas at work in the SharePoint list.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Your example is exactly like one of the formulas i tried, and it works. But i need to format the the date as you have done in column "DateAsText".

Comment: Yes i want the column to to formated as date and date only. And thing i found strange with this, is when i added JSON code to one of the columns the date shows up like 2018-07-06T22:00:00Z. If you try format your column DateAsDate with a bit of JSON code i think you see whats the problem.

Comment: This is the first time you mention JSON. What JSON code are you applying to the column?

Comment: {
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-weight": "bold"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}

Comment: The above creates the error, but the error also occurs with other script

Comment: If i remove JSON code all dates are showing up like 2018-07-09. But when the dates later are picked up by Flow it will print them in the wrong format 2018-07-09T22:00:00Z

Comment: That's why I was looking for a way to print the date as text, but I have not figured out how to add [ContractLength] to the start date

Comment: Unfortunately the suggested code from Ron Rosenfeld does not work, it gives an error message and can not be saved, but that's just how I want to do that if possible

Comment: The URL in your JSON sample is not valid. Please don't put the clarifications into comments. Please take the [Tour] and learn [ask]. Then edit your question and add the details. The comments are not for chatty brain dumps. You can delete your existing comments and post a comment to alert followers of your question when you have made an edit to your post.